# How many users can firebase handle?

Tags: firebase

I found online that firebase can only handle up to 100 users. Does this mean that after 100 users sign up, you will be forced to switch to a higher plan? That seems like a very low user count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit you're referring to is the limit for the number of concurrently connected users to Firebase Realtime Database on the free Spark plan.  Once you upgrade to a payment plan, your project will allow 200,000 simultaneously connected users.  This is not the total number of users, just the number of them that are currently running your app.  This limit does not apply to other Firebase products (there are over a dozen).

I suggest reading over the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) carefully to understand the limits for paid and unpaid projects, for each of the individual Firebase products.